# Casting from mobile hotspot phone

Tags: wifi-hotspot, chromecast, smart-tv

I'm on android 6.0.1. My main and only Internet is my phone. I don't have a router, Access Point, nor switch in my home. I use the mobile hotspot feature so other devices can connect to the Internet. My TV connects to the mobile hotspot as well. I am trying to cast from my phone to my TV but it doesn't seem to find it. Other devices have no problem. It's this at all possible to have mobile hotspot and be able to cast from the same device?

Answer (score 5):

Its possible, it is much easier if you have **two devices** (e.g 2nd smartphone, tablet or PC)

- Create a mobile hotpot AP using the **secondary** device.
- Once setup, connect the **primary** device (where you are going to setup chromecast) to the mobile hotspot AP and the TV
- Setup the chromecast as normal with the primary device and since the setup is once off you don't necessarily need to use the secondary device after inital setup. The Chromecast stays configured to the hotspot's wifi until otherwise reconfigured.
- The trick is to setup the Chromecast  **and use the same WiFi settings** when creating your hotspot. Chromecast doesn't look for a specific router as the source of the wifi signal. It just looks for hotspot name (SSID) and tries to connect using the stored encryption and password
- The consequence is that you just use the same WiFi settings when configuring mobile hotspot for the primary device.

Acknowledgements

- [Chromecast Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chromecast/xC5J-KSCRUo/MNdx6AcjEQAJ)
- [Casting from Android device using mobile data?](https://www.reddit.com/r/Chromecast/comments/2mi5pt/casting_from_android_device_using_mobile_data/)

Comment: Try to keep both the devices as similar as possible. In my testing:

Secondary (Moto G4) with Primary (Moto G3) only worked if I used an open wifi hotspot (no password). However, it didn't work if I tried to use a authenticated WiFi (with exact same credentials and name). My guess is that it was because the G4 _supports_ 5Ghz, and the G3 does not (The hotspot was on 2.4GHz in both cases.

Answer (score 4):

It was hard to do but I did it, my Chromecast put out a wifi network labeled "Chromecast7002.b" I connected to it with my note 4 (the one I would later be using as a hotspot) and engaged the setup.

Once I got it to ask which wifi to connect to I chose other, and for simplicity sake labeled it "Hopefully this works" and had it unprotected. I then set up my hotspot to match (without completely closing out Google home) and turned it on.

Then I used a moto z force and connected that to my hotspot, at this point I could see both the Chromecast and the phone connected to hotspot, and had to wait for the Chromecast to give up trying to connect, so I could reengage setup from the moto z force, afterwards it worked brilliantly.

Comment: Please format your answer for better readability.